CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleMLKit/PoseDetectionAccurate"
I'm building an ios app using flutter and after I implemented library from pub dev mrz_scanner in my app, I had errorr after I run

arch -x86_64 pod install

the current error is display as
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleMLKit/PoseDetectionAccurate":
  In Podfile:
    google_ml_kit (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_ml_kit/ios`) was resolved to 0.6.0, which depends on
      GoogleMLKit/PoseDetectionAccurate (~> 2.2.0)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `GoogleMLKit/PoseDetectionAccurate (~> 2.2.0)`.

You have either:
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

I updated the target runner in my pod file as below
target 'Runner' do
 # Flutter Pod

      use_frameworks! #add here

      pod 'Firebase/Auth', '10.22.0'
      pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 7.1'
      pod 'GTMSessionFetcher/Core', '~> 3.3'
      pod 'GoogleMLKit/MLKitCore', '3.2.0'
      pod 'GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition', '~> 3.1.0'
      pod 'GoogleMLKit/FaceDetection', '~> 3.2.0'
      pod 'GoogleMLKit/PoseDetectionAccurate', '~> 2.2.0'
      pod 'GoogleMLKit/ImageLabelingCustom'
      pod 'GoogleMLKit/DigitalInkRecognition', '~> 2.2.0'
      pod 'Firebase/Storage', '10.22.0'

      copied_flutter_dir = File.join(__dir__, 'Flutter')
      copied_framework_path = File.join(copied_flutter_dir, 'Flutter.framework')
      copied_podspec_path = File.join(copied_flutter_dir, 'Flutter.podspec')
      flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

I updated my pubspec.yaml file to add depencies
google_mlkit_text_recognition: ^0.4.0
google_ml_kit: ^0.7.3

Then tried running these commands as in the issue from error running pod install
flutter clean
rm -Rf ios/Pods
rm -Rf ios/.symlinks
rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
flutter pub get
cd ios
pod install # (or on an M1+ mac: arch -x86_64 pod install)
cd ..
flutter build ios
flutter run

even after trying all of that still having the same error.

Try to set an iOS Deployment Target (not a minimum deployment) version to 14, it should help.
You can do it from Podfile or with XCODE
